# How to include file path which is a Python string in Outlook email body?

Tags: python, email, path, outlook

I am new to python and trying to build a python script which will send an email that consists a file path. I got a sample code to send email in python which is working fine after few hiccups with pywin32 and psutil module. The email is received but I am struggling to include a file path in the email body which is extracted in the same code. I am pasting the code below with comments.Can you please help me with this issue?

**EDIT:** I am running into weird issues. I kept trying and these are the issues I encountered:

- 1. Program runs fine when I manually run it on cmd prompt and provide an input path
     C:\Users\<>\Desktop\Exp>python sendemail.py  C:\Users\<>\Desktop\Exp\xxx.txt
- 2. I see not output when I run the code with regedit, not sure why?
- 3. If I move the python code to C:\tools and run it manually on cmd prompt, I see the DLL load failed error:

     **C:\tools>python sendemail.py C:\Users\<>\Desktop\Exp\xxx.txt**
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "sendemail.py", line 1, in 
     import win32com.client as win32
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com__init__.py", line 5, in 
     import win32api, sys, os
     ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I am using Python 2.7.13 [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. Windows 10 OS 64b

```
import win32com.client as win32
import psutil
import os
import subprocess
import sys

# Drafting and sending email notification to senders. 
def send_notification(path):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'jdoe@email.com' 
    mail.Subject = 'File Location'
    mail.body = 'Hi User,\nThis is the file location\nFile=%s;' %path
    mail.send

# Open Outlook.exe.

def open_outlook():
    try:
        subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Outlook.exe'])
        os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Outlook.exe");
    except:
        print("Outlook didn't open successfully")

##############################################################
# Extract path of file (using regedit to trigger Python script)
###############################################################

#Filepath gives me the path where file is located: C:\Users\<>\Desktop\Exp
filepath = sys.argv[-1]   

#split filepath to move one directory up to give me C:\Users\<>\Desktop 
spath = filepath.split('\\')[:-1] 

#Check if user is running script on the correct file
file=filepath.split("\\")[-1]
if file != 'xxx.txt':
    with open("ErrorMessage.txt","w+") as output:
        output.write("INPUT ERROR:Please run script on xxx.txt\n")
    os.startfile("ErrorMessage.txt")
    sys.exit()

#Final path which I need to include in my email body
path = '\\'.join(spath) 

#Checking if outlook is already opened. If not, open Outlook.exe and send email
for item in psutil.pids():
    p = psutil.Process(item)
    if p.name() == "OUTLOOK.EXE":
        flag = 1
        break
    else:
        flag = 0

if (flag == 1):
    send_notification(path)
else:
    open_outlook()
    send_notification(path)
```

Comment: What's the output you're seeing right now?

Comment: The email received is this:
Hi User, 
This is the file location
File=;